# Cakephp find syntax for 'OR' and 'AND' complex join conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a task planning app and I'm attempting to fetch tasks based on two criteria: either they have a due date within the next 2 weeks, or the task itself is ending within 2 weeks.  Here is my non-working code:

```
  $conditions['AND'] = array(
        'OR'=>array(
            'AND'=>array(
                'Task.due_date >'=> $now,
                'Task.due_date <'=> $twfn
            ),
            'AND'=>array(
                'Task.end_time > '=> $now,
                'Task.end_time <' => $twfn
            )
        )
    );
```

There are additional conditions, hence the outer `$conditions['AND']`

The SQL log shows:

```
WHERE ((((`Task`.`end_time` > '2015-06-30') AND (`Task`.`end_time` < '2015-07-14')))
```

Which implies that the `OR` isn't being evaluated. If it's relevant, every task has an `end_time`, but not necessarily a `due_date`.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this: the `AND`s should be in array, because you are giving the same key(AND) for the array and the last one will be used

```
$conditions['AND'] = array(
    'OR'=>array(
        array(
            'AND'=> array(
                array(
                    'Task.due_date >'=> $now,
                ),
                array(
                    'Task.due_date <'=> $twfn
                )
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'AND'=>array(
                array(
                    'Task.end_time > '=> $now,
                ),
                array(
                    'Task.end_time <' => $twfn
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

more examples from docs
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I figured it was a syntax issue, but I ended up learning something too. Cheers!